# How to deploy React app (create-react-app) to Back4App?

Tags: reactjs, parse-platform, create-react-app, back4app

I've created an React app with `create-react-app` and I want to deploy it to Back4App.

The problem is I want to deploy the `build` folder and not the `public` folder (which I understand is the default for Back4App / ParsePlatform).

So far, I haven't found any way to config `deploy` to use anything other than the `public` folder.

Any solution / workaround to this?

Comment: all `build` does is create the files and put them in the build folder on your development machine, but they don't have to be in a build folder on your server;  you can simply copy the contents of the build folder into the public folder.

Comment: But it creates kinda of a circular loop as the build process also uses the public folder as source — cleanest way would be to configure the deploy folder to whatever we need

Comment: I guess I'm just confused here;  it seems as though the workflow for back4app assumes you are going to deploy directly from your source and not use `build` at all.  https://www.back4app.com/docs/javascript/react-template

Comment: You're right. I'm just double checking if there is any way around it. It would be better for back4app to have `public` as default but let us configure `build` (or other) if required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using B4A CLI, one of the easiest ways to deploy a create-react-app is, firstly, changing the **build** script into your package.json as below snippet:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build && cp -r build/* {{PATH-TO-YOUR-B4A-APP}}/public",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
...
```

As you can see, you just need to move all content inside create-react-app build folder to the public folder of your cloud code. After that, move to your app path and run **b4a deploy**.

Also, you could add a step to clear all public folder content before move the new stuff, but be careful with this step.

Otherwise, you could access the Back4app Parse-Dashboard into the Cloud Code Functions and deploy all the build stuff in public folder using the browser interface.

[This](http://react-b4a.back4app.io/) is a live demo of a create-react-app deployed in Back4App.

Comment: Thanks I’m going to try the dashboard option. Changing the build script seems to work just for one deployment as we will lose the default index.html in the public folder after running the first time. Right?

Comment: I've edited the snippet to a better understanding, you'll have two different projects: one is your ReactJS and the other is your Back4App App. So the Build script will move all the built content from your ReactJS project to your cloud code public folder so that the public folder into your ReactJS project will keep the same. It's kind of confused 'cause the folders have the same name, but I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: I get unauthorized when navigating to another page https://react-b4a.back4app.io/rr please how do i resolve that @LucasAlencar?